# Can I omit "people" after "more and more"?

Tags: word-order

Can I omit the word "people" after "more and more", taking into account that "people" had already appeared in the same sentence?

This is my case:

> He thought that, if he portrayed himself as a kind of prophet fighting a crowd of unbelievers, the skepticism of the **people** would diminish and **more and more** would accept his account as something that really happened.

Comment: Yes, you can definitely omit "people." "More and more" is a pronominal phrase there, functioning just like the redundant noun phrase "more and more people."

Comment: But somehow when I read this, it seems like something should be there. I would at least use "more and more *of them*".

Comment: @user3169 I think one would feel prompted to add "of them" if the antecedent were more specific, not the generic "people," for example: "He thought that if he ... the skepticism of his followers would diminish and more and more of them would accept..." Notice that "more" is the comparative of superiority of "many," and "many" can be used alone to mean "many people," for example: "His third novel is regarded by many (=a lot of people) as his best."

Comment: "Notice that "more" is the comparative of superiority of "many," and "many" can be used alone to mean "many people," I like this explanation. It is quite convincing.

Answer (score 5):

You can omit **people** because of its proximity to **more and more** is understood to refer to *people*

> *skepticism of the people*...**more and more**

if instead you had

> *the people's skepticism*... **more and more**

it would usually be understood to refer to *skepticism*, without additional context

Answer (score 3):

You could omit **people** if it were clear that "more" is an adjective in this sentence. The reason I would advise against it in this case is that "more" also has meaning as an adverb, which in this case looks like it could be modifying the verb **accept**.
We then end up looking for the subject of **accept**, and the obvious choice (syntactically) is also the subject of the verb **diminish**, namely, **skepticism**. But semantically, that's nonsensical.

In the end, there's only one meaning for the sentence that makes sense, and that meaning is the one you wanted to convey; but you run the risk of making some of your readers have to read the sentence twice to figure it out.